What proposals, if any, have been made regarding overtourism within an open borders framework?
The idea of "open borders" refers to a policy of having no restrictions on the movement of people across borders, typically including immigration, emigration, and tourism. Despite its use in political debate to characterize parties perceived as lax on immigration, few or no major parties in most countries support an open border policy. Still, the idea enjoys some (at least nominal) support among public intellectuals.
Although the idea is usually discussed in the context of immigration, more than tourism, and in reference to more populous countries, such as the USA, there are countries which are very popular as tourist destinations compared to their size, often small islands such as the Bahamas, which is a major cause of overtourism, something that has become a political cause and led to protests in some countries.
This applies not just to countries, but to smaller divisions, such as the Greek island of Santorini, which limits the number of cruise ships that can dock, but nonetheless has over 3.5 million vistors per year. It seems at least possible that some open border proposals would limit the ability of these destinations to restrict tourism, or might cause a portion of overtourism of small destinations to become permanent immigration (e.g. if just one in 100 people who visited Santorini stayed there long-term, the population would more than triple in a year).
Have any advocates of universal open borders addressed possible effects of universal open border policies on small countries or other jurisdictions affected by overtourism? If they have, do they see this as a concern, and if so, what proposals have they made to mitigate such effects?

I am not sure how related the 2 concepts are.  Overtourism is typically localized while over-immigration is more country/regional.  For all intents and purposes tourism from affluent countries (where the visitors are unlikely to be an "illegal immigration risk") is already pretty much open borders, is it not?  There may be an increasing backlash against overtourism, but where it happens you see a local split between winners (those making good $ from tourists) and losers (some of the rest) amongst the locals.  That's not a national level open border debate, mostly, except in small countries

i.e. for each telegenic coverage you may find a lot more people who would not want to suppress tourism overmuch.  And that even more in locations with fewer alternative economic avenues than Barcelona, which, along with places like Paris or Rome, is kind of an exception in having a really diverse economy and being very touristic at the same time.

@ItalianPhilosopher - That's true, but (a) the fact that tourism to a lot of these destinations is currently nearly unrestricted doesn't mean that there are no proposals to address it (there are many), and I am wondering how people who identify as open borders advocates think about them, and (b) open borders would presumably allow some tourism to turn into permanent immigration without any restrictions, so I am curious how this gets addressed in the context of these smaller countries. I'm not particularly interested in countries like the USA, which could probably be ten times as large.

That's why I gave the example of Santorini,  which already imposes substantial restrictions on the number of plane/cruise arrivals, and is not precisely easy to immigrate to long-term, but still gets several hundred times its population in tourists each year. It's an extreme example, but there are a bunch of other small islands that are more or less similar.

Generally speaking, in the past (not the perhaps slightly faddish modern incarnation), a lot of the concerns in this domain are more geared towards getting lesser numbers, of higher value tourists.  Cruise ships are almost the antitype there - the visitors shop for trinkets, eat lunch, but eat breakfast and dinner on their ship and don't stay in hotels (I grew up on St Maarten).  Very low value, except for near-harbor tourist shops.  Another is the traditional broke&loud Lager Lout a la Malaga/Amsterdam/Daytona Beach.  This Q is the first time I've ever heard of open borders in that regard.

@ItalianPhilosopher - Well, I think that's partly because open borders is very much non-mainstream despite the number of times one hears the word (can anyone name one governing political party that has actually opened its borders to everyone since WWII?) and overtouristing has only recently become prominent, so their interaction has been of primarily theoretical interest.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Well, I am kind of done blabbing here.  Maybe someone else will see more of a connection, but I don't.  But I do note that talk about both overtourism and open borders are recent trends, so others may have better insights.

"if just one in 100 people who visited Santorini stayed there long-term, the population would more than triple in a year" Where would they stay? Santorini isn't that big.

Common measure against overtourism are:

Tourism taxes: Charge tourists money if they want to travel to or stay in a popular destination. It either makes the destination less attractive for tourists on a budget, or the local government makes enough money to counterbalance the negative impact of mass-tourism. This is what Venice tries since 2024. But it's not really a new idea. You have that all over the world. For example, the city of Amsterdam in the Netherlands charges 12.5% extra on all tourist accomodations.
Using zoning restrictions to hinder the tourism industry. Don't give building permits for tourism-oriented hotels, prohibit subletting of private homes to foreigners and prohibit people living abroad from buying real estate (a demand of the anti-tourism movement on the Baleares).

Note that all examples I provided here are within the EU and experience most of their tourism from EU citizens enjoying the open border policy within the EU. So they are at least legally possible within an open border framework.
Do they have their intended effect? That's a matter of debate.
What amount of tourism is healthy for any given location is often a very fiercely debated subject in local politics. On the one side, there are the citizens who are afraid of tourism impacting their lifestyle, driving up prices and damaging the environment. On the other side, there are citizens whose income depends directly or indirectly on the tourism industry and see it as an essential economic factor for the region. Those two interests need to be balanced against each other. So with any anti-tourism measure mentioned above, you will have a lot of people claiming they go too far, with others claiming they don't go far enough.

The European Union has open borders internally and guarantees freedom of movement to EU citizens. The European Parliament (EP) is the legislative body of the EU, which makes it a proponent of open borders, at least within a certain set of countries.
Overtourism is also a problem in the EU.
To help countries deal with the issue, the EP released reports on overtourism within the EU. I found a report from 2018 , which also outlines policy measures already taken at different locations.
The relevant section is 5.4 on page 101 and it includes the following measures to limit tourist influx:

Distributing tourists to other locations or travel times via promotions and infrastructure investment
Higher prices via taxation
Stopping development of new hotels through zoning laws
Banning certain short-time rentals (like AirBnB)
Passing laws restricting tourists or particularly bad tourist behaviour (e.g. alcohol bans)
Informing possible tourists about crowd sizes and capacities.

Although not mentioned explicitly in the report, I would also add cruise ship bans (like the one recently enacted in Venice) as a measure to limit the number of tourists.
There are also measures which reduce overtourism by increasing a location's capacity for tourists:

Investments in security and infrastructure
Investments in the lives of residents (e.g. safeguarding affordable housing)

Note that none of these measures include closing borders; they do not stop people from legally coming to a place.
They do make it more difficult to stay there by increasing prices or reducing the total capacity. Limiting accomodation should be most effective, as very few tourists like to sleep on the street during their vacation.
Since overtourism is not just a question of the total number of tourists in a location, other measures either increase the capacity by turning a remote location into a larger city or restricting particularly disruptive behaviours by tourists. The latter option can also be used, if you want to keep the income from tourism while changing the type of tourist that visits.
Which measures are most effective depend on the specifics of the location and the vision for its future so there is no comprehensive list but there are certainly many options, some of which are promoted within the open borders framework of the EU.
I want to close with a frame challenge to the assertion that migration and overtourism are necessarily linked. Hawaii has problems with overtourism and ~3/4 of its visitors come from the US itself, so border closures would not help. The same seems to apply to the Taj Mahal in India.

"Passing laws restricting tourists" and "cruise ship bans" seem dubiously consistent with open borders, the first self-evidently, and the second for the same reason that saying that people could not cross a border in a car would be in tension with it. Still, +1 for a concrete example.

@Obie2.0 A cruise ship ban does not prevent a ship or its passengers from crossing a border and entering a country, it simply limits where the ship (but not the passengers) can go after it’s inside the country. That’s not a breach of the principle of open borders, any more than it would be if they declined to build an airport on an island that you might like to fly to.

@MikeScott - I'm not sure I find that credible. "You can cross the border but don't go this far in your mode of transportation" sits kind of uneasily. The analogy would be not building a harbor, I think.

@Obie2.0 Note that the Cruise ship ban is not limited to foreigners. Even a domestically owned cruise ship where all people on board are citizens would fall under this ban. Also, in the example of regards to Venice, there is no restriction on cruise ship passengers. They can still go to Venice, just not on board their ship. They instead land at some other port nearby and take a coach.

@Obie2.0 The key difference is that the restriction is not based on the nationality of the passengers. It applies to Italians using cruise ships just as much as it does to foreigners, and therefore is not a border restriction.

@MikeScott - I don't think that is so straightforward. A country that never lets anyone enter or leave, regardless of their nationality, would then not have a border restriction by that standard, and something like North Korea would be closer to open borders than almost any other country. But the point of this is not for me to be the arbiter on what is really an open borders policy, but how self-declared advocates think about certain issues, so that part of the answer is as good as the rest in that regard.

To be clear, the EU does not have any governing parties that support universal open borders, as far as I know, but it is still a decent analogy for the types of policies discussed in the question.

Open borders are in general not in conflict with any desired restrictions to tourism because tourists are legal visitors. Imposing absolute numerical bounds would be in contradiction to open borders but making tourism more expensive in general is not. This can be fairly simply achieved by fees on hotels and especially low cost alternatives like camping spots. Countries that happen to be islands can also impose fees on all travel to and from the island.
So the general rule would simply be 'everyone is welcome to come as a tourist, as long as they afford it' and the price is regulated so that any overtourism is curbed to an acceptable level.

I think this answer could benefit from showing that this is a position that some/most open borders advocates hold. Although I don't quite understand it in its present form, since the idea behind open borders is that any vistors are legal visitors. Say that you try to charge someone a fee to enter your country because you suspect that they are there for vacations. They don't want to pay it, or cannot, so...your immigration and customs enforcement physically stop them from entering (not really open borders)? Or lets them in anyway (not really an effective fee)?

@Obie2.0 The fee is payed for staying in a hotel or similar, not at the border. So at the border you don't need any barrier. Sources would be nice, but at the high abstract level this is discussed (see for example your linked wikipedia article) I don't think there are any official documents discussing that some possible side effect is not actually relevant in practice.

Hmmm. Well, even though I personally suspect that the necessary measures would be rather more complicated in practice than just raising resort fees—and in the extreme, perhaps even in tension with the ideal of open borders—I'll grant that this is enough of a justification that advocates could plausibly see it as the solution. If you can cite at least one published advocate saying this, I will accept the answer.
